# Difference between using VertexPositionNormalTexture and VertexPositionTexture

Tags: c#, xna, vertex

What are the differences between using VertexPositionNormalTexture and VertexPositionTexture in XNA? Does the GPU apply culling if the normal points away from the camera, or does it do that automatically? Is it just more data to send to GPU?

What are the advantages and disadvantages, and in what situations would each one be applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage is that you can pass a calculated vertex normal to your shader and the shader can use that information in the render, for example you can implement smoother lighting that more closely approximates curved surfaces by interpolating the normal across each triangle and using this interpolated normal for lighting rather than the normal of the triangle.

I suppose you could use this information for culling, but it's not generally what it's used for.  You don't need vertex normals to cull because generally it's easily done just by calculating the direction of the normal of the triangle, rather than each vertex.

When you say 'does the GPU apply culling...' remember that the days of fixed pipeline processing are gone, the GPU does what you tell it to do in your shader code.  At the end of the day you can put whatever information you want in to your vertex stream,  and use that information however you want in your shader,  the possibilities are endless.

Comment: Thank you. And I suppose, that if I am barely doing any shader work at all, I don't need to bother with using the normal vertices?

Comment: You must be using a shader, but presumably you are just using one of the default shaders.  If that shader does not require a normal then there is no need to send the information so yes you can just use the VertexPositionTexture vertex format.

Comment: Just one more question; is it less efficient to use the vertex with normals, since it carries more data?

Comment: Simple answer is yes. But I'd be surprised if you notice the difference.  It will take the GPU fractionally longer to read the data. However if you have the normals calculated anyway then passing them to the GPU anyway gives you the opportunity to switch in more complex shaders later without worrying about having to change the vertex pipeline, so if you've got them I'd be tempted to send them.  If you don't have the vertex normals calculated then why would you want to use this vertex format?  It's like saying is it less efficient to send texture coordinates - yes - but you still want to do it.

Comment: ...actually since this is the cube engine I'm struggling to see what value vertex normals could have - your surfaces are never curved and you'd need to write a shader to use them in which case you can calculate them in the shader.  So probably no value in using them in your vertex at all.